# Copying subfolders to new folders with same superfolder names

Tags: directory

Please feel free to direct me to past forum posts that have addressed this question, but I haven't been able to find them so far.

I'd like a code I can use in Terminal that allows me to accomplish the following, but can scale to more folders. tfMRI_SOCIAL_RL is the folder being moved.

firstdirectory/1/MNINonLinear/Results/tfMRI_SOCIAL_RL --> seconddirectory/1/MNINonLinear/Results/

firstdirectory/2/MNINonLinear/Results/tfMRI_SOCIAL_RL --> seconddirectory/2/MNINonLinear/Results/

firstdirectory/3/MNINonLinear/Results/tfMRI_SOCIAL_RL --> seconddirectory/3/MNINonLinear/Results/

Thanks very much, 
Brandon

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to move the folders `tfMRI_SOCIAL_RL` including their parent folders but not other files or folders which may exist in the parent folders.

If `firstdirectory` and `seconddirectory` are in the same parent directory, you can use:

```
cd /path/to/firstdirectory && mkdir ../seconddirectory && find -type d -name tfMRI_SOCIAL_RL -exec cp -r --parents '{}' ../seconddirectory \; -delete
```

If `firstdirectory` and `seconddirectory` are not in the same directory, use

```
cd /path/to/firstdirectory && mkdir /path/to/seconddirectory && find -type d -name tfMRI_SOCIAL_RL -exec cp -r --parents '{}' /path/to/seconddirectory \; -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use rsync. It's much more powerful than copy.

1) if you just want to copy the whole contents of one directory to another (which doesn't seem to be the case as it's very trivial) then cp -r is enough but rsync would be faster.
rsync

2) If you want to ability to continue to sync the two folders with incremental changes, then rsync is the way to go (cp can't do that)

2) If you want to copy only the folder names (i.e. tree structure) but no files, then rsync still can help. See
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsdosx-copying-directory-structures-trees-rsync/